# Here routing API v8 is not returning toll info anymore

Tags: routes, here-api

Since yesterday I'm not receiving toll information anymore. I'm currently getting a notice object in the response with severity 'info' and error tollDataUnavailable. Someone knows what happened, and if the service will be up and running again?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please confirm on the service you are using with the sample request? Also please confirm if you are still facing the issue?

Regards, Here Team

Comment: Dear Customer, Could you please confirm on the service used?